# Collections Shuffle Method has Null Objects

Tags: java, collections, shuffle

I am working on a Java project that involves Card objects and a Deck object. When I made my Deck, I have an ArrayList that has all 52 Cards in it. However, when I use the shuffle method in Collections, four Card objects are turning to null.
The Card class works fine, and when I print out the Deck before the shuffle method, all 52 Cards are there. Once I shuffle the Cards in the Deck, that's when I get the four null methods.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
public class Deck {
public ArrayList<Card> pack = new ArrayList<Card>();
public int spades = 1;
public int hearts = 1;
public int diamonds = 1;
public int clubs = 1;
public String s = "spades";
public String h = "hearts";
public String cl = "clubs";
public String d = "diamonds";
public Deck(){

}
public void makeDeck()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++)
    {
        Card c = null;
        if (clubs < 14)
            c = new Card ("Clubs", clubs);
            clubs++;
            pack.add(c);
        if (spades < 14)
            c = new Card ("Spades", spades);
            spades++;
            pack.add(c);
        if (hearts < 14)
            c = new Card ("Hearts", hearts);
            hearts++;
            pack.add(c);
        if (diamonds < 14)
            c = new Card ("Diamonds", diamonds);
            diamonds++;
            pack.add(c);

    }
}

public void showDeck()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(pack.get(i));
    }
}

public String CardNumber (int index)
{
    return (pack.get(index).toString());
}

public int Number (int index)
{
    return pack.get(index).CNum();
}

public void Shuffle()
{
    Collections.shuffle(pack);
}
```

}

Comment: Quite simply, you need braces around the body of your `if` statements. Get an IDE to format your code and you'll see what you've *currently* got. Java isn't like Python - it doesn't use whitespace to determine where blocks end.

Comment: `Collections#suffle` is not the culprit here.

Comment: There is only 13 numbers from 1 which are less than 14.  This is where using a debugger is helpful because you would see that 4 `null` values are added before you call shuffle.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your `if`-statements are flawed, you need braces:

```
if (clubs < 14) {  // <--
    c = new Card ("Clubs", clubs);
    clubs++;
    pack.add(c);
}  // <--
```

Same goes for the other `if`-statements in `makeDeck`.

Note that, in Java, if you don't include the braces then only the *first* statement after the `if` will be included in its body.

For example:

```
// 1
if (condition)
    A
    B
```

is equivalent to

```
// 2
if (condition) {
    A
}
B
```

The spaces before `A` and `B` in snippet 1 are not relevant when it comes to determining what gets included in the `if`-statement's body.

Answer (score 0):

I absolutely guarantee that Collections.shuffle() is not inserting null elements. They must already be in there before you shuffle.

Your fill loop is horribly over-complicated and as a result broken. Just use i to generate the card for each suite. The other answer already explained what's wrong with the if statements.

```
String[] suites = new String[] { "Hearts", "Clubs", "Spades", "Diamonds" };


for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
   for (String suite: suites) {
      pack.add(new Card(suite, i));
   }
}
```

Comment: @Christian yes, you are right. Just updated my answer.